# python - Why is it mandatory to use return statements in recursion?

Tags: python, recursion, return

Consider the following example:

```
class Parser:

    def __init__(self):

        while True:
            input = raw_input("Logic: ")
            if input == 'quit':
                break

            self.readFunction(input)

    def readFunction(self, input):
        for i, char in enumerate(input):
            if input[i] == '(' and input[i+1] != ')':
                print input[i+1:-1]
                return self.readFunction(input[i+1:-1])
```

Here's what the input in the console looks like:

```
user@laptop:~/Projects/pr$ python main.py 
Logic: a(b(c(d(e()))))
b(c(d(e())))
c(d(e()))
d(e())
e()
```

(Logic is the user input)

**My question:** Why is it mandatory to use `return self.readFunction(input[i+1:-1])` instead of `self.readFunction(input[i+1:-1])` to accomplish recursion? If I omit the `return` statement, the actual output of the program is mixed up.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand?  You have to use `return` because you want the function to return a value.

Comment: In this code, it appears that return is being used to break out of the 'for' loop.  A 'break' following the self.readFunction line would also accomplish the same thing.

Comment: But it does NOT return any value. Does the return statement interrupt the for loop or what? Because if I don't use the return statement, the different loops get intertwined or something.

Comment: @mkimball Thanks! Could you please explain what happens without the return statement? Does the loop continue even after the function call?

Comment: Yes, the loop continues from where it left off, and repeats the printing of the slice which was passed to the nested readFunction call.

Comment: Oh, that's why... I thought of it as if they were two separate threads (the for loop and the newly called function).

Comment: The return statement does not have any direct connection with the fact that you used a recursive algorithm to solve a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not mandatory to use return with recursion, even though it usually makes recursion practical - what *is* "mandatory" is to write an *equivalent* algorithm. Removing the `return` breaks this equivalency, even though the actual return value is discarded.

For instance, the following with [`break`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#break) would work:

```
def readFunction(self, input):
    for i, char in enumerate(input):
        if input[i] == '(' and input[i+1] != ')':
            print input[i+1:-1]
            self.readFunction(input[i+1:-1])
            # No return - but like return this EXITS THE LOOP
            # when the termination condition is met.
            break
    # Breaks to here with an implicit "return None" at the end
```

Answer (score 2):

The function of the return is that the for loop ends (because the function it is in ends). Without the return, it goes on (why wouldn't it) and then the code doesn't work well.

Tip: if this confuses you, it's a good idea to get pen and paper and work through the code by hand, step by step.

Comment: This pretty much clears it up. Initially, I thought that without the return statement both the newly called function and the for loop continue executing in paralel, thus making the code not work. Is this correct?

Comment: There is no 'in parallel', as all calls happen on the same thread.  However, the same data is processed by more than one call.  (in sequence, not in parallel.)

Comment: No, you have to do some pretty special things to get things running in parallel in Python. The newly called function starts executing, at some point it finishes, and then the original function continues just as it would had it called any other function. In this case it will do another recursive call, but with a different value of `i` (namely the index of the next `(`).

Answer (score 0):

Without returning you can't call the next function which will take the now updated values and make further changes to them.

One uses recursion because he doesn't want to use loops or return values to a variable and call functions over and again with the help of loops again.

That'd not only take more memory in larger programs but also increase the lines of code.

Instead, one can simply use the recursive calls which will not only decrease the memory use but also the lines of code and to an extent it will simplify the program as well.